# Split long jade array variable into multiple lines

Tags: javascript, arrays, pug

Is there any way of writing an array that's defined within a jade template with line breaks and indendations, purely for ease of reading reasons.

For example, something like this:

```
- var array = [
-   ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','k','l','m','n'],
-   ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','k','l','m','n'],
-   ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','k','l','m','n'],
-   ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','k','l','m','n']
- ];
```

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872555/multiple-lines-for-long-attribute-value-in-jade) about multiple lines in attribute values, but I don't think I can use the same answers here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no elegant way to do this. You could work around your problem by using a variable for each array line

```
- var a1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','k','l','m','n'];
- var a2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','k','l','m','n'];
- var a3 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','k','l','m','n'];
- var a4 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','k','l','m','n'];
- var array = [a1, a2, a3, a4];
```

Or if you prefer a one dimensional array

```
- var array = [];
- array.push('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','k','l','m','n');
- array.push('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','k','l','m','n');
- array.push('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','k','l','m','n');
- array.push('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','k','l','m','n');
```

These are just work arounds since there is no elegant syntax to achieve this in jade currently.

Answer (score 1):

repeat of this question : [Multi-Line Array Literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254491/multi-line-array-literal/35143377#comment58732367_35143377)

You can use the `-` as a block. (adding any white spaces after the `-` will not work however, new line needs to follow immediately)

```
-
  var array = [
     'a',
     'b'
  ];
```