# Multiple line objects in Jade

Tags: pug

How do you write objects in Jade over a number of lines?

At the moment I'm having to write the objects like so

```
.grid-col
  - var content = {name: 'brand',title: 'Dull designers',copy: 'Posted by Jamie Ellul',tags: ['test-1','test-2','test-3']}
  include patterns/panel--sub
```

Ideally I'd like to write my objects like so

```
.grid-col
  -var content = {
    name: 'example',
    another: 'one'
  }
  include patterns/panel--sub
```

any thoughts?

UPDATE

Found the answer here:
[Multiple Lines for Long Attribute Value in Jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872555/multiple-lines-for-long-attribute-value-in-jade?rq=1)

Comment: [It's not possible at this time, but there's a feature request on Github](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/796)

Comment: Found the answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872555/multiple-lines-for-long-attribute-value-in-jade?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi-Line Array Literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254491/multi-line-array-literal)